# Laravel client specific text

Tags: php, laravel, localization

He! We have a platform with different clients, some texts on the platform should be different for each client (but all in english). so for example for one client there could be a title saying `todays metrics` and for another client it could be `your statics`. Now this is a very simple example but we also use this for explaining certain calculations we do for clients which are client specific and therefore the way we explain is different.

Laravel has localization but if feels a little wrong to use this because for us it has nothing to do with the location of clients. Also laravel has some basic localization files for the auth system for example. So I prefer to not change this system to make our client specific translations. Now my other idea was to make a helper function

```
<?php
 require_once('/path/to/translation/array');

 function getClientTranslation($param)
 {
   return $clientTraslation[$param];
 }
```

And then register this in a service provider to use it in blade like `{{ getClientTranslation('todays metrics') }}`

What would you guys think would be the best approach here. Or is there a better solution I'm not thinking about right now?

Comment: Localization is not the answer indeed. There is probably not an infinite amount of possibilities. You'll have to define statuses for each one of them, even if you have to calculate a status, and start from there. You could use the status as a 'flexible' @include in blade.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean by define a status and include it in blade?

Comment: How are you determining which message to show to what client? Add a field and for example 1 means "todays metrics", 2 means "your statics" etc

Comment: As a programmer, you are instructing a computer. Keep it simple. If you figure out what user can see what, the rest can be solved in blade. If small changes are needed (you wanted to use internationalization) you'll have to do that on database level (more flexible) or internationalization-like files. For example lang/en/metrix.php  and statics.php where keywords are equal. Then again, these are suggestions. It is up to you to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I would assign each user a type and I'ld use that information to know what message to show. You could even store the messages in the user_types table. On your blade file you would be able to do something like this:

```
{{ auth()->user()->type->message }}
```

Comment: in this example type would be the client or?

Comment: Type would be the user type. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I assumed that your client is an authenticated user, so when I talk about an user and you talk about a client, we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: Well in my case clients have users. so a client can have multiple users. But I understand your idea!